# Symfony2 unit testing cannot instantiate class in test class

Tags: php, symfony

I am working with Symfony2 and trying to write some PHPUnit test for one of my classes.

This is what I have done so far following Symfony2 testing Docs i created a folder under Tests directory with a file myClassTest.php ini it:

```
<?php

namespace Test\TestBundle\Tests\Template;

use Test\TestBundle\Dto\Template\myTemplate;

class myTemplateTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function testMyMethod()
    {
        $test = new myTemplate();
    }
}
```

This is myTemplate:

```
<?php
namespace Test\TestBundle\Dto\Template;

use Test\TestBundle\Doctrine\DatabaseRepository;
use Test\TestBundle\Validation\ValidationClass;

class myTemplate
{


    /**
     * @var ValidationClass
     */
    private $validate;

    /**
     * @var DatabaseRepository
     */
    private $db;

    /**
     * @param ValidationClass $validation
     * @param DatabaseRepository $databaseRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        ValidationClass $validation,
        DatabaseRepository $databaseRepository
    ) {
        $this->validate = $validation;
        $this->db = $databaseRepository;
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
 Argument 1 passed to Test\TestBundle\Dto\Template\myTemplate::__construct() 
must be an instance of Test\TestBundle\Validation\ValidationClass, string given, 
called in Dev/project/src/Test/TestBundle/Tests/Template/myTemplateTest.php
```

More Errors:

This error points to the injected service in the construct $validation

```
Dev/project/src/Test/TestBundle/Dto/Template/myTemplate.php:42
```

This error corresponds to the instantiate class of myTemplate class

```
Dev/project/src/Test/TestBundle/Tests/Dto/Template/myTemplateTest.php:15
```

I understand the errors well i think I do but i have no idea how to fix it and these errors are shown when i run `phpunit` test.

Comment: Are you expecting the php new operator to use the dependency injection container?  If so then you will be disappointed.  If you want to use the container then take a look at the integration testing section in the Symfony 2 documentation to see how to start up the kernel and grab the container from it.

Comment: well these  ValidationClass $validation,
        DatabaseRepository $databaseRepository are injected services into myTemplate class....

Comment: How do you expect the new operator to inject them?

Comment: Any reason you included the R tag? (Doesn't look it, so I removed it.)

Comment: Sorry was away for some time so i cannot test a class if there are injected services in it...? and this is exacly my problem why I cannot test who can I text a class that injected services

Answer (score 0):

For testing with PHPUnit, you should use Mocks and Stubs for imitation logic in your depends classes.

Before initialize `myTemplate` in test case, you should create a mock of this objects, or create original objects.

```
$validationMock = $this->getMock('ValidationClass');
$dbRepositoryMock = $this->getMock('DatabaseRepository');

$myTemplate = new myTemplate($validationMock, $dbRepositoryMock);
```

And after you can use invocation system for control called methods.

For more information, please visit PHPUnit site:
https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html